# laravel, eloquent where condition get result in yajra datatable

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatables

I asked this question twice but didn't get any answer, I have two tables: Country and Region so to get all regions you must select country_id which I did with normal table but how can I do this using ajax 
thank you in advance

Model of Region:

```
public function getRegionsByCountryID($countryID)
{
    return $this
   ->leftJoin('countries', $this->table.'.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')
    ->select
        (
            $this->table.'.*',
            'countries.name as country_name'
        )
        ->where('country_id','=',$countryID)
        ->orderBy('id','asc')
        ->get();

}
```

Jquery

```
     $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('get-regions') }}",
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                'country_id': country_id
            },

            success: function(data){
            },

        });

    });
```

Controller

```
   public function getData(Request $request)
     {
       $data = $this->SourceData->getRegionsByCountryID($request->input('country_id'));
        return Datatables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
      ->addColumn('Actions', function($data) {
            return '....';

        })
                ->rawColumns(['Actions'])
                ->make(true);
}
```

Blade

```
     <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered datatable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>No</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Country</th>
                                <th>Avaliable</th>
                                <th width="150" class="text-center">Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: what error you are getting.?

Comment: Im not getting any error, just want to know how to do this!!!! Im not familiar with yajra datatable